# What happens with adjacent string literal concatenation when there is a modifier(L, u8, etc.)

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals

It is valid in C and C++ to break a string literal because the preprocessor or the compiler will
concatenate adjacent string literals.

```
const char *zStr = "a" "b"; // valid
```

What happens when string literals are prefixed with `L` (wide characters), `u` (UTF-16), `U` (UTF-32), `u8` (UTF-8), and raw string literals (`R"foo(this is a "raw string literal" with double quotes)foo"`)?

For example, is the following allowed:

```
const wchar_t *zStr = L"a" "b"; // valid?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++0x your example is valid according to [lex.string]/p13:

> ... If one string literal has no
>   encoding-prefix, it is treated as a
>   string literal of the same
>   encoding-prefix as the other operand.
>   ...

In C++03 this same section said that this code had undefined behavior:

> ... If a narrow string literal token
>   is adjacent to a wide string literal
>   token, the behavior is undefined. ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that particular undefined behavior require a compiler to issue any sort of diagnostic in cases where it would opt to produce generate code that launch the nuclear missiles?  I could understand a standard allowing a compiler a choice of either expanding the narrow string to wide without a diagnostic or regarding such concatenation as malformed, but allowing diagnostic-free Undefined Behavior would seem the worst of all possible worlds.

Comment: @supercat:  Undefined behavior generally implies that anything at all can happen.  The code could do exactly what you intended.  It may compile, it may not.  It could make the computer hover over the nearest single's bar.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Why do standards people allow full-blown undefined behavior in cases like that, where the compiler should clearly *know* whether it's going to generate a valid string literal or not?  I understand that guaranteeing that dangling pointer access won't cause nasal-demons would be unacceptably expensive, but what possible benefit is there to allowing unrestricted UB for a malformed concatenated string?

Comment: @supercat: I don't have a good answer for you. I too think undefined behavior is way over used in the standard. There is a study group on the C++ committee to address this issue. It is my sincere hope that they do so aggressively. gcc in particular is known for doing dangerous optimizations when it detects undefined behavior. For example, code that accidentally creates UB in checking for overflow can be optimized by the compiler such that the overflow check is eliminated. It is a really bad situation, and you don't want to be sitting in a car running such code in a safety critical context.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: The overflow-check thing is another example where UB has gotten way out of hand.  IMHO, things like integer overflow should have been a category between Undefined Behavior and Implementation-defined behavior: an implementation need not specify any specific behavior, but must specify all possible outcomes which may include unbounded Undefined Behavior *for implementations which expressly specify it*.  Implementations would be encouraged to avoid specifying unbounded Undefined Behavior, however.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Additionally, I think C really needs a better range of numeric types--preferably parameterized; when using such types, signed vs. unsigned behaviors should *not* be affected by a machine's `int` size.  Otherwise I see no feasible, reliable, and efficient means of writing truly-portable numeric code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that particular example is allowed by C++0x. Any combination of prefixless and L-prefixed literals will be treated as though all are L-prefixed.

EDIT: Citation -- N3242 (current C++0x working draft) §2.14.5/13:

> In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated. If both string literals have the same encoding-prefix, the resulting concatenated string literal has that encoding-prefix. If one string literal has no encoding-prefix, it is treated as a string literal of the same encoding-prefix as the other operand.

Comment: This is incorrect. ISO 14882:2003 C++ standard 2.13.4/3 says: In translation phase, adjacent narrow string literals are concatenated and adjacent wide string literals
are concatenated. **If a narrow string literal token is adjacent to a wide string literal token, the behavior is
undefined.** The Visual C++ compiler I have [emits a diagnostic (C2308) for mismatched strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86888ehe.aspx).

Comment: There's more than one standard to choose from, this is covered by c++0x.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes, but maybe those standards agree on this topic?

Comment: @In silico : I've added a citation, I should have specified C++0x originally.

Comment: @ildjarn: I have removed my downvote. Thanks for providing a C++0x-specific citation.