# Recursive preprocessor macro for strings

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have some code that needs Unicode strings for the most part, but I want to make it conditional (ie, `TEXT("string")` expanding to `L"string"` or `"string"`, depending on settings). For these, I use the macro:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#    define VSTR(str) L##str
#else
#    define VSTR(str) str
#endif
```

The main complication with this is printf format strings, which use `%s` and `%S` for same-encoding and other-encoding strings, respectively. Some strings come from similarly conditional APIs (`TCHAR` and similar), while some come from set APIs (mostly C-string only). When using `_tprintf` and family, the function used can vary making `%s` and `%S` conditional as well, and they may need to be flipped around. To handle this, I defined macros to the appropriate format elements:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#    define VPFCSTR(str) "%S"
#    define VPFWSTR(str) "%s"
#    define VPFTSTR(str) VPFWSTR(str)
#else
#    define VPFCSTR(str) "%s"
#    define VPFWSTR(str) "%S"
#    define VPFTSTR(str) VPFCSTR(str)
#else
```

Now, this all works fine, but forces the syntax:

```
VSTR("Beginning of a format string, with a string '") VPFTSTR VSTR("' included.")
```

I would like to be able to use a syntax like:

```
VSTR("Beginning of a format string, with a string '", VPFTSTR, "' included.")
```

For Unicode, this needs to expand to:

```
L"Beginning of a format string, with a string '" L"%s" L"' included."
```

The only complication is the variable number of arguments, all of which need to be transformed in the same manner (one by one, if necessary).

My first idea was to use `__VA_ARGS__` to handle this, using empty arguments, like:

```
VASTR(str, ...) VSTR(str) VASTR(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Unfortunately, as macros can't be used in their own definition, this fails. I then attempted a proxy:

```
VASTR2(...) VASTR(__VA_ARGS__)
VASTR(str, ...) VSTR(str) VASTR2(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The proxy method doesn't appear to work either.

Is there a way to handle running the same macro on each argument of a(nother) macro, which takes a variable number of arguments? Or, if not, is there an equivalent? If compiler-specific, MSVC10 is preferred, but anything is of interest.

Comment: If you use `printf`, I have no pity.

Comment: @DeadMG There was some time put into avoiding it, actually. Unfortunately, interfaces break anything templated and most operator-based solutions (stringstream, boost.format, variadic templates) and/or force them onto the caller. `printf` on one end or the other ended up being the most elegant solution (perhaps it would've been best to not log at all, at that point). :p

Comment: @DeadMG If you have any ideas on how to avoid it, though, I would be delighted to hear them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive macro expansion is not possible in C/C++.

Not sure, but C++0x allows you to omit encoding prefix for string literal concatenation. Thus you can try design your macro to prepend `L` only to the first string literal and use it as follows:

```
VSTR("Beginning of a format string, with a string '" VPFTSTR "' included.")
```

Please, correct me, if I'm wrong.

### UPD.

A similar Unicode-related question: [What happens with adjacent string literal concatenation when there is a modifier(L, u8, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179384/what-happens-with-adjacent-string-literal-concatenation-when-there-is-a-modifier)

Comment: It appears you are correct, which would make things simple enough. Now to find out compiler support for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Boost.Preprocessor library, and these additional macros, you can apply your VSTR macro to each argument:

```
//Your VSTR macro for one argument
#define VSTR_EACH(str) ...

/**
 * PP_NARGS returns the number of args in __VA_ARGS__
 */
#define PP_NARGS(...) \
         PP_DETAIL_NARG((__VA_ARGS__,PP_DETAIL_RSEQ_N()))
#define PP_DETAIL_NARG(args) \
         PP_DETAIL_ARG_N args
#define PP_DETAIL_ARG_N( \
          _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
         _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
         _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
         _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
         _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
         _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
         _61,_62,_63,N,...) N
#define PP_DETAIL_RSEQ_N() \
         63,62,61,60,                   \
         59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
         49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
         39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
         29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
         19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
         9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 

//Convert agruments list to a BOOST_PP_SEQ so we can iterate over it
//This is two macros in order to avoid the bug in MSVC compilers
#define DETAIL_PP_ARGS_TO_SEQ(size, tuple) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(size, tuple)
#define PP_ARGS_TO_SEQ(...) DETAIL_PP_ARGS_TO_SEQ(PP_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), (__VA_ARGS__))

//The macro used inside of BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH
#define VSTR_SEQ_EACH(t, data, x) VSTR_EACH(x)

#define VSTR(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(VSTR_SEQ_EACH, ~, PP_ARGS_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```