# CreateWindowEx shows chinese gibberish instead of original text

Tags: c++, winapi, direct3d, createwindowex

I have a problem. I wanted to document my tool development, so instead of mspaint-ing a date on top of screenshot, I wanted to make the window name carry the date and time data. But instead of the string I've got only chinese characters.

[image: gibberish]

Here is my code where I want to assign the string to CreateWindowEx():

```
char *wndName = "Asphyx V0.01 (Build Date: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ ")\0";

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                      L"WindowClass",
                      (LPCWSTR)wndName,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      300,
                      300,
                      wr.right - wr.left,
                      wr.bottom - wr.top,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      hInstance,
                      NULL);
```

EDIT: Guys, I appreciate your answers, but all of them gives me this

```
Error 29 error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
```

and the only somewhat working stuff was a yet deleted answer, but it gave me this:

[image]

he used this code:

```
char title[256];
sprintf(title, "Asphyx V0.01 (Build Date:  %s - %s)", __DATE__, __TIME__);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                      L"WindowClass",
                      title,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      300,
                      300,
                      wr.right - wr.left,
                      wr.bottom - wr.top,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      hInstance,
                      NULL);
```

Comment: Casting is bad, mmkay.

Comment: also plus one for south park reference :D

Comment: For completeness, and not because it's a good idea, the other way to fix the problem would be to call `CreateWindowExA` instead of `CreateWindowEx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the standard if one of the strings has an encoding prefix, the rest of the string that don't, will be treated as having the same prefix.

This is not the case with Visual Studio. It is a bug.

You need to use a wide string and prefix every string literal with `L` including the macros:

```
#define WSTR2( s ) L##s
#define WSTR( s ) WSTR2( s )

wchar_t *wndName = L"Asphyx V0.01" WSTR(__DATE__) L" " WSTR(__TIME__) L")";
```

Comment: this still gives the concatenating mismatched strings error

Comment: The " " needs an L too.

Comment: @JonathanPotter D0h. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is because you are using cast to convert char to LPCWSTR, replace

```
char *wndName = "Asphyx V0.01 (Build Date: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ ")\0";
```

to

```
 wchar_t *wndName = L"Asphyx V0.01 (Build Date: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ ")";
```

Now you don't need more of cast in second parameter of CreateWindowEx.

```
wchar_t *wndName = L"Asphyx V0.01 (Build Date: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__ ")";

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                  L"WindowClass",
                  wndName,
                  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                  300,
                  300,
                  wr.right - wr.left,
                  wr.bottom - wr.top,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  hInstance,
                  NULL);
```

Comment: This will fail to compile because `__DATE__` by itself expands to a `char*` string.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: are you sure it doesn't simply expand to a quoted *string*?

Comment: @Jongware It works because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179384/what-happens-with-adjacent-string-literal-concatenation-when-there-is-a-modifier However this is undefined, only c99 and newer versions defined this: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR10-C.+Do+not+concatenate+different+type+of+string+literals

Comment: still it gets a concatenating mismatched strings error

Comment: @JonathanPotter: okay, I got it. Until this precise moment I ... *assumed* ... it was just a Preprocessor thing, as I never had any reason to doubt that.

Comment: @Jongware: That's what I mean. It expands to a narrow string, not a wide string. And you can't concat `L"foo" "bar"` without some macro magic.

Comment: I though this was a C question. So my comments aren't correct for C++. Look at the question tags Felipe.

Comment: I put a different answer below

Comment: error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings with your answer too